# str_ireplace not work with utf-8 characters

Tags: php, replace, utf-8

I use **str_ireplace** (not **str_replace**) to replace some words, but it doesn't seem to work with utf-8, e.g. "đ".

There are any solution for this issue?

Many thanks.

Example input

```
 str_ireplace("đ", "b", "bĐb");
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example script in which this is not working? If I try `echo '<?php echo str_ireplace("đ", "b", "bđb");' | php`, I see `bbb` as expected. [The manual](https://www.php.net/str_ireplace#refsect1-function.str-ireplace-notes) also states that the function is binary safe, so it should be able to correctly handle multibyte strings.

Comment: Yes, it will work with your example but this is not work:  str_ireplace("đ", "b", "bĐb"); 
=> Đ is UPPER case of đ.
But this work fine:  str_ireplace("h", "b", "bHb");

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Yes, `str_ireplace` would not work in that situation, because it's not Unicode aware. You could use a regular expression with [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/preg_replace) instead, such as `preg_replace("/đ/iu", "b", "bĐb");`.